# Turning longitude and latitude to a Point

Tags: java, jmapviewer

So im using JMapViewer and on this map i have some mapmarkers with a certain longitude and latitude

So to insert a text field next to this certain mapmarker i need to turn the longitude and latitude into a Point with X and Y to provide it to the setBound of the label.

And thanks !

Note that i need to do this so that if i moved the map the text moves with the map so when the map marker disappears the text disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JMapViewer` has several variations of `getMapPosition()` that return a `Point` given the geodetic coordinates. You can see how the method is used in `paintMarker()`, called by `paintComponent()`. See `OsmMercator` for ellipsoid and projection details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert angular coordinates (lat, lon) to Cartesian coordinates (x, y). Take a look at GeoTools' [GeodeticCalculator](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html). In particular use an azimuth of 0 and 90 degrees to compute the horizontal and vertical distance from the origin of your Cartesian map.